# Are hazard ratios additive?

Tags: hazard, ratio

I have data from Cox regression which indicates that compared to a baseline condition

condition A => has hazard ratio= 2
condition B => has hazard ratio= 6.5

Is it possible to say if condition A and B were experienced simultaneously one should expect a cumulative hazard ratio of 8.5?

Is it appropriate to sum hazard ratios this way? Or it is mathematically incorrect? I have read stuff around but I just cannot find a convincing answer.

Comment: The summing is incorrect, but you'll have to provide a bit more information about how your data were structured to get an answer about the best way to proceed. In particular, were condition A and condition B entered as separate predictor variables into the Cox regression, or were they two separate levels of the same predictor variable? Were there any cases with both condition A and condition B?

Comment: First of all thanks for your answer. Condition A and B are 2 separate and independent variables. Actually they are 2 deleted genes operating in completely different pathways. I have no cases in which A and B are observed simultaneously.

Comment: reading a bit more I found that hazard ratio may be summed using their log: log(2) + log (6.5)= 0.693147181 + 1.871802177 =2.564949358; exp(2.564949358) = 13. If this is correct, the predicted combined effect should be a hazard ratio = 13. Again, this is from my limited understanding.

Answer (score 4):

Think first about multiple linear regression. In that case, regression coefficients of independent predictor variables add. I suspect that's where you got the idea of adding the hazard ratios.

But the hazard ratios are *not* the coefficients in a Cox regression. Hazard ratios are obtained by exponentiating the Cox regression coefficients. So by the laws of exponents, summing coefficients means *multiplying* hazard ratios. This is what you figured out in one of your comments; 2 * 6.5= 13.

That said, I would be extremely hesitant to apply this rule to your situation. Mother Nature has beat me up too often, over my decades as a bioscientist, to let me believe that your two genes are really in "completely different pathways." Your lack of finding cases with both genes deleted might be a sign of synthetic lethality: you can get by if you have one or the other, but lose both and the cell (or organism) dies. Or perhaps one is functionally downstream of the other in some yet un-described pathway; then adding the loss of the second gene may have no additional effect. Without data on true functional independence you should proceed very cautiously.

Comment: I understand this perfectly. This prediction attempt is just for discussion sake and only under the hypothesis of additive effect of gene A and B. It is just a reference number to hypothesize possible scenarios. But I would like to be able to calculate that number even if it is an  approximation of the reality. Actually there is a 3rd gene involved in the study. When deleted this last gene will inactivate A, B and some other uncharacterized pathways. This 3rd gene will give me the upper ceiling for A+B   effect.

Comment: This site tries to develop a collection of answers that are useful for a broad readership, not just for the person who asked it. So I tend to include cautions that might not be obvious to someone who comes across a question and answer later, even if the OP is well aware of the issues.